# Flask send_file has can't completing the download

Tags: python, flask, download

I am trying to download a file using the send_file function in Python Flask, but it is not completing the download. I have tried using the following code:

send_file(somefile.7z), as_attachment=True)

just this function. can download, and response. but my chrome, the download does not complete

[image]

i was check this solutions

1. check internet stability
2. check console of flask
3. restart chrome